# Why are unit tests failing after migration to .Net6 ("The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this")

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm in the process of migrating a large .Net 4.x solution to .Net6, and now that I have the first few projects building successfully I thought I'd have a go at running the unit tests (MSTest project). However many tests are failing with the above message, specifically those that test code in a WPF project.

All tests pass in the 4.x solution. Why would they be failing in the .Net5 MSTest project, and is there a way to get them working?

**Edit**: I know unit tests shouldn't be testing UI functionality, but I want to point out that I'm unit testing MVVM view models. Having said this, there will always be something that needs the STA thread, whether it's setting the mouse cursor during a long running operation, or updating an observable collection from an event handler, requiring the use of the Dispatcher. I have written wrappers for this sort of thing, checking if I'm running in a unit test or whether the dispatcher is available. The failing code is typically where I've forgotten to use such wrapper classes, which (for whatever reason) worked fine in VS2019 and .Net Framework 4.x.

Comment: I have had problems in the past with background threads trying to change control values of the main frame that threw this error. I think WPF handles the controls differently for the forms unlike win forms. Are you migrating it from win forms too or just .NET 4 to .NET 6 core?

Comment: @byrd this is a WPF project, not winforms, and the error is only occuring during unit tests.

Comment: Have you considered forcing the tests to run on an STA thread.  If you are touching UI elements in your tests, the code should really be running STA.  Take a look at: https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-customize-test-execution.htm (looking for STA).  Since it involved marking the tests with an `[STATestMethod]` attribute, it also cleanly marks which tests are STA-specific

Comment: @Flydog57 I'll look into that thanks. Just curious though as to why they've run for many years in the 4.x solution. Could it be anything to do with which test adapter is installed?

Comment: It could be no one thought of it before. Now they check. Calling into UI elements is always flakey (it may work, crash or hang). Eventually some looked at unexpected bug reports and said "D'oh, it's an STA problem"

Comment: Are you running your tests in parallel?  I wouldn't usually have unit tests on ui.

Comment: @Andy: That's for NUnit, the OP mentions MSTest.  Oh well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how true this is but I read on a blog somewhere (which I can't find now) that MSTest in .Net Framework ran tests as STA, whereas in .Net Core/5/6 the tests now run as MTA.
I didn't want to switch thousands of unit tests to NUnit, so my solution was to create my own custom [STATestClass] and [STATestMethod] attributes as detailed here: https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-customize-test-execution.htm

Comment: Hi Andrew Stephens, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)